# Loading an image into UITableViewCell from an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have several hunderd `.jpgs` in `/Resources` within an iOS project.

Here is the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


     NSArray *allPosters = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"."];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

The above successfully loads all of the `.jpgs` into an `NSArray`.
I simply need to display all of the `.jpgs` within this array in `UITableViewCells` in a `UITableView`

Here is the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSDictionary *posterDict = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *pathToPoster= [posterDict objectForKey:@"image"];

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil ) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


            }

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:pathToPoster];
    cell.ImageView.image = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I know the issue is with `cell.ImageView.image`, but am not sure what the issue is? How can I grab each `.jpg` from the array and display in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *allPosters = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"."];
```

This will give you an array of paths (as suggested by the method name). Those paths are NSStrings. 
But you are assigning this array to a local variable, and this variable will be gone after you left viewDidLoad.

so you have to change it into something like this:

```
allPosters = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"."] retain];
```

Another one:

```
NSDictionary *posterDict = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *pathToPoster= [posterDict objectForKey:@"image"];
```

And this would definitely crash if you would have assigned the array correctly.

Change it into

```
NSString *pathToPoster = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Next one:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:pathToPoster];
cell.ImageView.image = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

UIImages imageNamed: doesn't work with paths, it needs filenames. And of course you want to assign the real image to the imageview and not the path to the poster. So change it:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[pathToPoster lastPathComponent]];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting 'Request For member 'ImageView' in something not a structure or union' though?

Comment: oh yeah, didn't found that. It's cell.imageView.image of course. Without capital I

Answer (score 2):

Try using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToPoster]` rather than `imageNamed`. And set the value to the UIImage object.

Comment: +1 Thanks, added that to  @fluchtpunkt's answer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a typo, but it should be:

```
//lowercase "i" in imageView
cell.imageView.image = [allPosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Also- you are creating UIImage *theImage, but then you don't use it.  What's going on there?